# iOS visualization of UISearchBar scope buttons change

Tags: ios, ipad, tableview, uisearchbar

After I clicked the cancel button the scope bar stands alongside the search bar ... but the code is:

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
[searchBar sizeToFit];
[searchBar invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
[searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
tabellaCanzoni.tableHeaderView = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar;
}
```

I want it to stay below the search, not alongside!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code all working right:

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
[_barraRicerca resignFirstResponder];
_barraRicerca.text = nil;
[_barraRicerca setShowsScopeBar:YES];
[_barraRicerca sizeToFit];
isFiltered=FALSE;
[tabellaVideo reloadData];
}
```